# Replace String in python with a sequence of Alphabet

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, replace, str-replace

I am writing a piece of python code to replace a sequence of Alphabet. I understand how to do it but unfortunately it just replacing the one have already replaced.

```
lines=[]
replacements = {'a':'s','s':'d','d':'f','f':'g','g':'h','h':'j','j':'k','k':'l'}

with open("wrongString.txt") as infile:
    for line in infile:
        for src,target in replacements.iteritems():
            line = line.replace(src,target)
        lines.append(line)

with open("decode.txt","w") as outfile:
        for line in lines:              
            outfile.write(line)
```

wrongstring.txt : asdfghjkl

After running the code, the result shows (encode.txt): ggggkkkll

The code does replacing "a" to "s", and keep replacing the "s" to be "d" till get "g" by somehow. I just want to replace "a" to be "s" then stop replacing it.

Can you guys help me to find a solution for it?

Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

use a *list comp* so you don't overwrite any replaced characters:

```
  line = "".join([replacements.get(ch, ch) for ch in line])
```

You also don't need to store all the lines, just write the lines as you go:

```
with open("wrongString.txt") as infile, open("decode.txt","w")  as outfile:
    outfile.writelines("".join([replacements.get(ch,ch) 
                                  for ch in line]) for  line in infile))
```

Comment: Nice! it works like a charm :D. thanks for much